# iOS background audio recording mutes incoming text messages

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, core-audio

My iOS application performs some long-running tasks for which I am recording noise while the application is in background mode.

I initialize the app's AVAudioSession with

```
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
```

and when the application goes into background mode I activate the session

```
NSError *err = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&err];
```

which makes the red top bar appear.

The problem is that incoming text messages are muted while the application is in background and the application recording.

How can I ensure that these are *not* muted?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting topic. Have you tried other background modes?

Comment: Yes, audio background mode seems to be the only one that works reliably.